# Как растягивать GridBagLayout как это делает BorderLayout и GridLayout?

Tags: java, swing, grid

Есть таблица из связки JLabel/JButton и JText, с помощью Grid'a задал им нужные пропорции, но при растяжении окна размеры (масштаб) компонентов не меняется. Как сделать, чтобы эти компоненты были расположены по всему окну независимо от его размеров?

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался сам. Нужно параметры weightx и weighty установить на 1, тогда компоненты будут растягиваться по всем осям